# Install and unistall Visual C++ redistributable

Tags: wix

I have a program written in C#. To install it, I use WIX installer. 
During installation I install Visual C++ redistributable using Merge

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Merge Id="Redist2" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)3rdPartCodecs\redist\Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
  <Merge Id="Redist3" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)3rdPartCodecs\redist\Microsoft_VC120_OpenMP_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
</Directory>
```

This redistributable is common for some other programms. How can I make uninstallation of my programm without uninstalling redist? Or ask question whether redist should be unistalled or not?

Comment: Philosophy: Don't ask users questions they can't answer. So, once a common library is installed, leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer is a component manager.

It is true that the smallest thing that can be selected for installation or uninstallation is a feature. Nonetheless, the smallest thing that is installed, upgraded or uninstalled is a component. Windows Installer tracks references to each component. So, if the user is uninstalling all of your features that reference msvcrt components, they may or may not be uninstalled, depending on references by other features still installed.

Basically, you don't need to consider what other installers might still need.